# What is the maximum fig.height for html output when using knitr

Tags: html, r, knitr

While creating an HTML doc using the excellent knitr package, I noticed that sometimes the script would crash and sometimes not. After much poking around, I realized that it was simply due to the fig.height parameter in the chunk header

This caused a crash:
    ```{r, heatmap_res, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, fig.height=200}

yet this was OK and yielded all graphs as expected:
    ```{r, heatmap_res, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, fig.height=100}

Here is a reproducible example using ggplot2's diamonds dataset:

````
---
title: "figheight"
author: "Hackr"
date: "June 24, 2015"
output: html_document
---

```{r, heatmap_res, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, fig.height=200}

library(ggplot2)

data(diamonds)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price, fill = depth)) + geom_tile() + facet_wrap(~ clarity + color, ncol = 1) 
```
````

So what is the maximum value allowed in the fig.height parameter?  Also what units is this value?  inches?

Thanks, Hackr

Comment: with `fig.height = 200` my R does not crash... it is laggy but runs.

Answer (score 2):

The [chunk option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) `fig.height` is in inches. Normally you do not want a figure of 200 inches tall, although in theory there is no upper limit of the figure height.